# React Native project build failed after installing new module

Tags: reactjs, build, module, installation, native

When I install any new module in my previously build React Native project and trying to run then it fails to build. I also uninstalled previously build app from my android emulator and tried again but it failed again. whats the actual problem and whats the solution? [image: my cmd screen when it fails to build]

Comment: Already solved this by "gradlew clean"